# How to properly capture multiple lines between two patterns

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing

I have an html file of which I am trying to search for a pattern, and when I find it, print all the lines that are between the set pattern. In my case it is everything between "pre and /pre" which contains a stem loop sequence. My goal is to sort through numerous html files and pull out these structures and place them in a list, that can be printed out as it would appear in the html file. I am having trouble properly capturing all the lines and printing them properly as it would appear in the picture. Currently I am only getting two lines printed , pre cugcaggcagaaguggggcugaca /pre and 
pre ccucaccaccccuucugccugca /pre

Why is it not capturing everything within the pattern and printing it appropriately? It is skipping over the span and span class.. I am not sure if I am approaching this problem correctly -- is there a better way to think about this? Thank you

```
fh_html = open("filename").readlines()
for line in fh_html:

    match_obj = re.search(r'<pre>.*</pre>', line, re.DOTALL)
    print(match_obj.group(0))
```

This is what the html code looks like on a page: 
[image]
\This is what the code looks like:

```
<pre>ggggc             <span class="sld">u</span>   - <span class="sld">c</span>   <span class="sld">ca</span>    agag 
     <span class="sld">cugcaggcagaag</span> <span class="sld">ggg</span> <span class="sld">g</span> <span class="sld">uga</span>  gggc    g
     ||||||||||||| ||| | |||  ||||     
     g<span class="sld">acguccgucuuc</span> <span class="sld">ccc</span> <span class="sld">c</span> <span class="sld">acu</span>  cccg    g
-----             -   <span class="sld">a</span> <span class="sld">c</span>   <span class="sld">cc</span>    cguu </pre>
```

This is the code:

Answer (score 0):

You're passing each separate line to the regex, instead of the entire text.

Try this:

```
text = open("filename").read()
match_obj = re.search(r'<pre>.*</pre>', text, re.DOTALL)
print(match_obj.group(0))
```

Comment: In this example I did not include my lines of code previously, but I have several operations I need to do that require me to go through the file line by line in a for loop. How can I capture these multiple lines without reading the entire text ? I guess I need to store each line and then add them all up at the end when I print it out? Also, when I do this it does not stop on the first occurence of /pre, and instead continues throughout the rest of the html file, printing many many lines.

Comment: Regular expressions are _greedy_ by default, meaning they choose to match the longest possible pattern.  If you have multiple occurrences of `<pre>` and `</pre>`, it will match everything from the very first `<pre>` to the very last `</pre>`, and treat all of the ones in the middle as simply part of the `.*` pattern.